# set-frame-size does not work on emacsclient

Tags: microsoft-windows, frames, emacsclient, emacs-daemon, daemon

I have set up Emacs daemon on Windows 10. My Emacs version is GNU Emacs 25.3.1

I have some code in my `init.el` which resizes the frame size automatically when Emacs starts up. The code is

```
;; Select a desirable font-size, frame position and frame size when Emacs starts up
(defun originalPosition ()
  (interactive)
  (set-frame-font "Courier New-14" t t)
  (set-frame-position (selected-frame) 100 50)
  (when window-system (set-frame-size (selected-frame) 82 28))
  )
(originalPosition)
```

This code used to work perfectly when I launched Emacs **normally** (not as daemon). However, emacsclient does **not** accept these settings.

Searching around for a solution, I realised that I need to use `after-make-frame-functions` . So I added an *extra* line to my `init.el`

```
(add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions (lambda (frame)(when (display-graphic-p frame)(originalPosition))))
```

After adding this line, every instance of emacsclient has **different** frame sizes (but uses the correct font size).

How can I get emacsclient to use the correct frame size for **every** instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `default-frame-alist` and it sets the correct frame size

```
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(height . 28)) ;; Vertical frame size
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(width . 82)) ;; Horizontal frame size
```

It works when Emacs is launched normally and also when Emacs is run as daemon.